# Generating random passwords using Secure random

Tags: java, security, random, passwords

I need to generate random passwords using secure random. I went through some of the examples provided and the answer provided by crowne for [how can I create a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741160/how-can-i-create-a-password)
is great and I have modified according to my requirements.

The problem is that the generated password should always start with alphabet. how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to enforce such a policy?

Comment: 1. create the initial letter 2. create the rest of the password 3. concatenate.

Comment: It's the requirement that has been specified. No idea why it is so? and are insisting to be according to the requirements specified.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
String password = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1) + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(7);
```

incase your password has 8 characters length

Comment: the password should be a mixture of alphanumeric and special characters

Comment: Try looking at some of the other methods in `RandomStringUtils`. See http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html. This should not be a difficult task for you now.

Comment: It is probably worth reading the Diceware page as well: http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html